# vmbuilder won't build "trusty" (14.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, kvm-virtualization, vmbuilder

I can use this command to create a working VM running the "precise" (12.04 LTS) Ubuntu release:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu -v --suite=precise \
  --libvirt=qemu:///system --arch=amd64 \
  --cpus=2 --mem=2047 --swapsize=4096 --rootsize=71680 --flavour=server \
  --hostname=xxx --mirror=http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu \
  --components=main,universe --addpkg=openssh-server --user=claus \
  --pass=xxxx --dest=/home/claus/vm-xxx --bridge=br0
```

This appears to work fine.

But if I replace "precise" with "trusty" (14.04 LTS), the build process halts after a few minutes.

In the log file from the unsuccessful "trusty" build, the last lines are:

```
2015-05-16 12:03 DEBUG   : I: Configuring ubuntu-minimal...
2015-05-16 12:03 DEBUG   : I: Configuring libc-bin...
2015-05-16 12:03 DEBUG   : I: Configuring initramfs-tools...
2015-05-16 12:03 DEBUG   : I: Base system installed successfully.
```

At this point, nothing further happens. The vmbuilder program hasn't terminated, but nothing is happening.

In the log file from the successful "precise" build, the above lines are followed by

```
2015-05-16 11:41 INFO    : Calling hook: configure_os
```

and the build process continues.

(I am running the commands on a "precise" (12.04) system.)

What am I doing wrong in the "trusty" build?